# New user registration Showing error " We Can't save the customer "

Tags: magento2, customer, register

Hello i am new on the magento 2 . suddenly i got the error when new user come on the site and try to register after filling information it is showing error as " We Can't save the customer "  . i am not able to understand why this is happening suddenly on my website. please let me know and suggest me any relevant answer for this query . my webSite Url is http://54.67.81.223/viewsonicstore

Comment: I have try but no any error displaying, page not redired on my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `core/mage/customer/controller/AccountController.php` and find function named `createPostAction()`. In that function add

```
die($e->getMessage());
```

Just after `catch (Exception $e) {`.
You can see what the problem is..

Don't forget to remove the additional line when problem will be fixed.

Comment: Hi @arshish i have been facing same issue how do i fix? please advise recently upgraded to 2.3.1 CE

Answer (score 2):

You can debug your code from controller of account create.

Path is `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`
go to `execute()` function and you can debug here. your error are generate from line no. 278 from above file.

Comment: @raklesh i have tried all the answers but no luck can you help on save customer issue. Recently we upgrade to 2.3.3 CE to 2.3.1 CE. Please advise

Comment: Hi @NagarajuK, do you found any solution on it actually i am also facing same error after Magento 2.2.4 to 2.3.4 upgrade while creating customer account.

Comment: Can you help me with this? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310454/we-cant-save-the-customer-error-while-creating-new-customer-after-migration-t

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen after a reboot.

Normal Magento > from Magento folder

sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /var

Bitnami Stack

sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var

It has something to do with the folder permissions changing after a reboot.

Someone else will be able to post the correct reason

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` and find function named `createPostAction()`. In that function add

```
die($e->getMessage());
```

Just after `catch (Exception $e) {`.
You can see what the problem is..

In Magento2, you have to add in

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php

In the function execute()

```
 die($e->getMessage())
```

Don't forget to remove the additional line when problem will be fixed.

Comment: Hi @arshad syed i have been facing same issue how do i fix? please advise

Comment: What  error it is showing to you

Comment: "We can't save customer". I looking for solution from the past 4 days still issue exists in my local system after upgrade from magento2.2.3 CE to magento2.3.1 CE. Could you please advise

Comment: When you added this line die($e->getMessage()); in createpost.php
 what error it is giving you.

Comment: If you have any module which will register customer then check that module

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @Arshad Syed let me check and get back to you. thanks

Comment: it throws "Email must be a valid email address". but i have used correct email format. can u suggest now. https://prnt.sc/ni4mpx https://prnt.sc/ni4mxv

Comment: check in admin panel 
customers-> All customers
check all emails correctly entered

Comment: Here my observation is customer record is saving (admin end checked) but it throws an error can't save customer in the frontend while registration

Comment: any 3rd party extension or custom extension  you are using. that will register a user

Comment: No, not using any 3rd party @arshad Syed

Comment: Hard guess from where this error is getting.

Comment: yes syed. that is what i am facing issue here let me check is there any alternative way to debug this.. thanks for quick response and assistance.

Comment: sorry. Becoz until we don't check code structure it difficult to say from where error is coming.
Ok . If you find the solution let us know. How you have solved that one.

Comment: No problem arshad. sure i will let you know.

Comment: Found any solution? I am also facing same issue.