# “We can't save the customer” error while creating new customer after migration to magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, customer-account, migration

I followed this answer(https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/114480/79909) to solve this error but it is showing -> Content must be string or resource; received "Magento\Framework\Phrase".

I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone help me.

Comment: can you please share the full error message with trace and scenario

Comment: which PHP version are you using?

Comment: First, it showed “We can't save the customer” error while creating a new customer. But it is creating the new customer and storing the info in the backend. The only problem is that it is displaying We can't save the customer in the frontend while creating new customer.

Comment: @ChiragPatel PHP 7.2.21

Comment: My Magento version 2.3.3. Migrated the old site from m1 to this version.

Comment: There are many reason for this error and PHP version is one of this. so i asked to you.

Can you print error code instead of error message. so it will be easy to solve.

Comment: Error code showing Content must be string or resource; received "Magento\Framework\Phrase".

Comment: @ChiragPatel any solution for this?

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam  did you find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this error when migrating a Magento 2.1 store to version 2.3.5.

Researching the error, I ran into this question a few times. So, I would like to leave my contribution so that I can help other developers.

Well, when trying to create a client user through the administration panel, after filling in all the necessary data, the client will be saved. But I received an error message, and the log would record something like:

```
[2021-08-17 12:29:35] .CRITICAL: Exception message: Content must be string or resource; received "Magento\Framework\Phrase"
```

The solution was to review the following email template `account_new_no_password.html`, I realized that the custom theme would overwrite the original template.

I needed to change the following statement:

```
<a href="{{$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[id:$customer.id,token:$customer.rp_token]] ,_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank" class="confirmation-button">Link</a>
```

To:

```
{{trans
'<a href="%create_password_url" target="_blank" class="confirmation-button">Link</a>'
         create_password_url="$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[id:$customer.id,token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])"
|raw}}
```

After that, the error no longer exists. Remembering that I took as base the original Magento template: vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/account_new_no_password.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The exception comes from `Zend\Mime\Part::setContent`.
This is called when the welcome email is sent.
For some reason, you are not sending a string or a resource as content.
Check what the `$content` looks like and where you are trying to send it by email.

Most probably there is something like `__('some text goes here);`.
To solve it transform it into `__('some text goes here')->render();`

Comment: Where can I find the content and those related details? I am new to Magento.

Comment: The error message is always a good place to start. It says "Content must be string or resource". Look for this exact string in the code base and start from there.

Comment: It's working`__('some text goes here')->render()` it's used to resolve an issue @Marius